# I want to change the width of my form built using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to change the width of my form inside a Flexbox. I am just learning to use it as of now. I searched in a lot of places and tried applying the solutions but nothing seems to work out. Please Help.

This is how I want my form to look.

[image: This is How I want my form to look]

This is how it looks now!
[image: This is How it looks now]

```css
 .contact {
                background: var(--light-bg);
            }
            
            .contact .box-container {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                gap: 3rem;
                /* justify-content: center; */
            }
            
            .contact .box-container .box {
                width: 60rem;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container .box h3 {
                font-size: 1.7rem;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container .box p {
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                color: var(---light-color);
                margin-bottom: 2rem;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container .box form {
                flex: 1 1 42rem;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container form .input-box {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container form .input-box input {
                width: 49%;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container form .input-box input,
            .contact .box-container form textarea {
                border-radius: 5rem;
                padding: 1.2rem 1.8rem;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                color: var(--black);
                margin: 0.7rem 0;
            }
            
            .contact .box-container form textarea {
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: 1rem;
                resize: none;
                height: 25rem;
            }
```

```html
    <section class="contact" id="contact">
            <h1 class="heading">contact us</h1>

            <div class="box-container">

                <div class="box">
                    <h3>address</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                    <h3>email</h3>
                    <p>ipsumdolor@gmail.com</p>
                    <h3>phone</h3>
                    <p>+91 1234 567890</p>
                    <h3>Fax</h3>
                    <p>(123) 972 3894</p>
                </div>

                <form action="">

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Number">
                    </div>

                    <textarea name="" placeholder="your message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn">
                </form>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you didn't set a width and height to your form so it's set to auto by default soo try this

```
.contact .box-container .box form {
flex: 1 1 42rem;
min-width:60vw;
heigh:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't Work

Answer (score 0):

it would be good idea to use media queries
vh and vw for width and height

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).